# findAll(Iterable<E> elements) not working in mongo repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo, mongorepository

This is my mongo repository

```
@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends MongoRepository<Stock,String> {
    Stock findStockByStockSymbol(String stockSymbol);
}
```

This is my `Stock` class

```
@Document(collection="stocks")
public class Stock {

    @Id
    private String stockSymbol;
    private String StockName;

    private Double basePrice;


    public String getStockSymbol() {
        return stockSymbol;
    }

    public void setStockSymbol(String stockSymbol) {
        this.stockSymbol = stockSymbol;
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return StockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        StockName = stockName;
    }

    public Double getBasePrice() {
        return basePrice;
    }

    public void setBasePrice(Double basePrice) {
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stock{" +
                "stockSymbol='" + stockSymbol + '\'' +
                ", StockName='" + StockName + '\'' +
                ", basePrice=" + basePrice +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am trying to get a List of `Stock` from a List of `stockSymbols`

```
stockRepository.findAllStockByStockSymbol(symbolList);
```

But it returns an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently spring-mongo was not able to understand my query. I got it working by specifying a custom query using `Query` annotation.

```
@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends MongoRepository<Stock,String> {
    @Query("{ 'stockSymbol' : { $in : ?0 } }")
    List<Stock> findAllStockByStockSymbol(List<String> stockSymbol);

}
```

Comment: Try this     `List<Stock> findByStockSymbolIn(List<String> stockSymbol);`